# Is it possible to open an embedded file on a specific page?

Tags: hyperlink, embedding, hypertarget

is it possible to create a hyperlink so that it opens a PDF document attached to a specific page?

I have discover that the `navigator` package allowed it via the following syntax: `\openfilelink{file name}[page]{text}`. However, this package seems to be too old to be used with a recent version of LuaLaTeX and seems not to be compatible with the popular `hyperref` package. So I use the newer packages `embedfile` and `hypgotoe`.

Is it possible to specify a "destination" page when opening a PDF file with `hypgotoe`?

Here is a MWE (with `TestFile.pdf` any PDF file containing several pages):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref, embedfile, hypgotoe}
\embedfile{TestFile.pdf}

\begin{document}
Hello world : \href[pdfnewwindow=true, page=2]{gotoe:embedded=TestFile.pdf}{test hyperlink}.% page=2 indicates for example that the PDF should be opened on page 2
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hypgotoe currently only supports named destinations. But you can add a page destination like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref, embedfile}
\usepackage{hypgotoe}

\embedfile{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}

\makeatletter
\define@key{HyGoToE}{pagedest}{%  
  \edef\HyGoToE@Dest{%
    /D [\the\numexpr#1-1\relax\space /Fit]%
  }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

Hello world : 
\href[pdfnewwindow=true]{gotoe:%
pagedest=8,%
embedded=example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}{test hyperlink}.
\end{document}
```